# Inventory for each player

Tags: java, bukkit

Pretty simple question, difficult solution, because I would need to edit my whole code.
Im doing a Harry Potter plugin, and you are able to select a spell after you right--clicked your "wand" (a stick in this case)
Now, I managed it to mess it up, because... Yeah, I created 1 Inventory for all. Everyone should be able to unlock different spells, and now when 1 changes, all change.

I created the Inventory in a seperate class, and via some methodes I can receive / set everything I need.
Now, I cannot find a way to receive the Player in the Inventory class without
1) removing the modifiers = cant access it anymore
2) the need to remove / rewrite 90% of my whole code
Would be more then just great if someone could solve it... Sitting for 3 hours now.

SpellInventory class:

```
package at.skyblock.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

public class SpellInventory implements Listener {

   // Erstellt bei Rechtsklick mit dem Zauberstab das Inventar, in dem die
   // Spells gesetzt werden können. (!Nur erlernte werden angezeigt, siehe ->
   // SpellUnlocks!)
   // Die hier vorhandenen createDisplays() werden noch zu den Spellbooks (also
   // SpellUnlocks class) gemoved.

   public static Inventory spells = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9,
       ChatColor.BOLD + "" + ChatColor.WHITE + "Choose your Spell");

   // Methode um dem Inventar auch von anderen Klassen (in diesem Fall
   // SpellUnlocks) Spells hinzuzufügen
   // Für die verarbeitung eines klicks auf eines der im Inventar vorhandenen
   // Items, ist die Main class zuständig

   public static void createDisplay(Material material, Inventory inv, int Slot, String name, String lore) {
     ItemStack item = new ItemStack(material);
     ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
     meta.setDisplayName(name);
     ArrayList<String> Lore = new ArrayList<String>();
     Lore.add(lore);
     meta.setLore(Lore);
     item.setItemMeta(meta);

     inv.setItem(Slot, item);

   }

   public static Inventory getInventory(){
   return spells;
   }

   // Selbsterklärend
   public static void removeDisplay(Inventory inv, Material material) {

     if (inv.contains(material)) {
       inv.remove(material);
     }

   }

   static {
     // Proceed to remove this section, and give all unlocks to the books
     // (see -> SpellUnlocks)
     createDisplay(Material.MOSSY_COBBLESTONE, spells, 6, "Petrificus Totalus", "Ganzkörperklammer Fluch");
     createDisplay(Material.TNT, spells, 7, "Bombarda", "Sprengzauber");
   }

}
```

Main class:

```
package at.skyblock.main;

import java.util.HashSet;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.FireworkEffect;
import org.bukkit.FireworkEffect.Type;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.Sound;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Firework;
import org.bukkit.entity.LightningStrike;
import org.bukkit.entity.LivingEntity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.TNTPrimed;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.FireworkMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;


    public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
       // Instanz der Main class wird in "SpellUnlocks" kreiiert
       private SpellUnlocks event = new SpellUnlocks(this);

       public void onEnable() {
         // Andere-Klassen Events werden regestriert
         getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
         getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(event, this);
         getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new SpellInventory(), this);
         // Fügt den Spellbooks die ItemMeta hinzu (Siehe funktion in SpellBooks)
         event.createSpellbooks();

         // Checkt im halben sekunden (20tick=1sec) Intervall ob der Spieler die
         // Sprüche schon hat, löscht sie falls nicht.

       }

       @EventHandler
       public void onSpellApply(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
         Player p = e.getPlayer();
         if (getConfig().getBoolean("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".hasUnforgivableCurses") == true) {

           SpellInventory.createDisplay(Material.BEDROCK, SpellInventory.getInventory(), 0, "Avada Kedavra",
               "Todeszauber");

         } else if (getConfig().getBoolean("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".hasUnforgivableCurses") != true) {
           SpellInventory.removeDisplay(SpellInventory.getInventory(), Material.BEDROCK);
         }
         if (getConfig().getBoolean("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".hasBasicSpells") == true) {

           SpellInventory.createDisplay(Material.FIREWORK_CHARGE, SpellInventory.getInventory(), 1, "Stupefy",
               "Schockzauber");
           SpellInventory.createDisplay(Material.REDSTONE, SpellInventory.getInventory(), 2, "Expelliarmus",
               "Entwaffnungszauber");

         } else if (getConfig().getBoolean("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".hasBasicSpells") != true) {

           SpellInventory.removeDisplay(SpellInventory.getInventory(), Material.FIREWORK_CHARGE);
           SpellInventory.removeDisplay(SpellInventory.getInventory(), Material.REDSTONE);

         }

       }

       // Selbsterklärend
       public void onDisable() {
         saveConfig();
       }

       // Checkt welcher Spell in Inventar ausgewählt wurde, und setzt diesen als
       // currentSpell für den Spieler
       @EventHandler
       public void chooseSpell(InventoryClickEvent event) {
         Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
         ItemStack clicked = event.getCurrentItem();
         Inventory inventory = event.getInventory();

         if (inventory.getName().equals(SpellInventory.spells.getName())) {
           event.setCancelled(true);
           if (clicked.getType() == Material.BEDROCK) {

             player.closeInventory();
             getConfig().set("MSPotter." + player.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell", "AvadaKedavra");
             saveConfig();
           } else if (clicked.getType() == Material.FIREWORK_CHARGE) {

             player.closeInventory();
             getConfig().set("MSPotter." + player.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell", "Stupefy");
             saveConfig();
           } else if (clicked.getType() == Material.REDSTONE) {

             player.closeInventory();
             getConfig().set("MSPotter." + player.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell", "Expelliarmus");
             saveConfig();
           } else if (clicked.getType() == Material.MOSSY_COBBLESTONE) {

             player.closeInventory();
             getConfig().set("MSPotter." + player.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell", "PetrificusTotalus");
             saveConfig();
           } else if (clicked.getType() == Material.TNT) {
             player.closeInventory();
             getConfig().set("MSPotter." + player.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell", "Bombarda");
             saveConfig();
           }
         }

       }

       // Hauptteil: Checkt bei Linksklick mit dem Zauberstab, welcher Spell
       // gesetzt ist, führt diesen dann mit Partikeln sound on effekten aus.
       @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
       @EventHandler
       public void useSpell(PlayerInteractEvent e) {

         final Player p = e.getPlayer();
         if (e.getAction().equals(Action.LEFT_CLICK_AIR) || e.getAction().equals(Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
           if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.STICK)) {
             Location loc = p.getTargetBlock((HashSet<Byte>) null, 20).getLocation();

             final Firework f = (Firework) p.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.5, 0), Firework.class);
             FireworkMeta fm = f.getFireworkMeta();

             if (getConfig().getString("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell").equals("AvadaKedavra")) {
               if (getConfig().getBoolean("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".cooldowns.AvadaKedavra") == false) {

                 getConfig().set("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".cooldowns.AvadaKedavra", true);

                 p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERDRAGON_GROWL, 1.0F, 0);

                 fm.addEffect(FireworkEffect.builder().flicker(false).trail(true).with(Type.BURST)
                     .withColor(Color.GREEN).withFade(Color.BLACK).build());
                 fm.setPower(5);
                 f.setFireworkMeta(fm);

                 this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                   public void run() {

                     f.detonate();

                   }
                 }, 2L);

                 for (Entity en : f.getNearbyEntities(1, 1, 1)) {

                   if (en instanceof LivingEntity) {
                     LivingEntity le = (LivingEntity) en;
                     LightningStrike ls = (LightningStrike) le.getWorld().spawn(le.getLocation(),
                         LightningStrike.class);
                     le.setHealth(0);

                   }
                 }

                 this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                   public void run() {
                     getConfig().set("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".cooldowns.AvadaKedavra", false);
                   }
                 }, 6000L);
               }
               // #################################################################################################

             } else if (getConfig().getString("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell").equals("Stupefy")) {

               fm.addEffect(FireworkEffect.builder().flicker(false).trail(true).with(Type.BALL)
                   .withColor(Color.AQUA).withFade(Color.BLUE).build());
               fm.setPower(3);
               f.setFireworkMeta(fm);
               this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                 public void run() {

                   f.detonate();

                 }
               }, 2L);

               for (Entity en : f.getNearbyEntities(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)) {

                 if (en instanceof LivingEntity) {
                   LivingEntity le = (LivingEntity) en;
                   le.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(3));
                   le.setVelocity(new Vector(le.getVelocity().getX(), 1.0D, le.getVelocity().getZ()));
                   if (le.getHealth() > 3) {
                     le.setHealth(le.getHealth() - 1.5);
                   }
                 }

               }

             } else
               if (getConfig().getString("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell").equals("Expelliarmus")) {

               p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.SHOOT_ARROW, 1.0F, 0);
               fm.addEffect(FireworkEffect.builder().flicker(false).trail(true).with(Type.STAR)
                   .withColor(Color.RED).build());
               fm.setPower(1);
               f.setFireworkMeta(fm);
               this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                 public void run() {

                   f.detonate();

                 }
               }, 2L);

               for (Entity en : f.getNearbyEntities(1, 1, 1)) {

                 if (en instanceof Player) {

                   Player target = (Player) en;

                   if (target.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.STICK)) {
                     if (target.getInventory().getItemInHand() != null
                         && target.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType() != Material.AIR) {

                       ItemStack wand = target.getInventory().getItemInHand();
                       p.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(p.getLocation(), wand);

                       target.getInventory().remove(Material.STICK);

                     }
                   } else {
                     p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Dein Gegner hat keinen Zauberstab in der Hand!");
                   }

                 }

               }

             } else if (getConfig().getString("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell")
                 .equals("PetrificusTotalus")) {
               p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ITEM_BREAK, 1.0F, 0);

               fm.addEffect(FireworkEffect.builder().flicker(false).trail(true).with(Type.BALL)
                   .withColor(Color.WHITE).build());
               fm.setPower(1);
               f.setFireworkMeta(fm);
               this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                 public void run() {

                   f.detonate();

                 }
               }, 2L);

               for (Entity en : f.getNearbyEntities(1, 1, 1)) {

                 if (en instanceof LivingEntity) {
                   LivingEntity le = (LivingEntity) en;
                   if (le.isOnGround()) {
                     le.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW, 100, 10000));
                     le.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP, 100, -10000));
                   } else {
                     p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Du kannst nur Gegner am Boden treffen!");
                   }
                 }

               }

             } else if (getConfig().getString("MSPotter." + p.getUniqueId() + ".currentSpell").equals("Bombarda")) {

               p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.EXPLODE, 1.0F, 0);

               TNTPrimed tnt = loc.getWorld().spawn(loc, TNTPrimed.class);
               tnt.setFuseTicks(0);

             }
           }

         } else if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) || e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
           if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.STICK)) {
             p.openInventory(SpellInventory.spells);
           }
         }
       }

    }
```

Comment: "Now, I cannot find a way to receive the Player in the Inventory class without the need to remove / rewrite 90% of my whole code" - yes, rewrite it. The entire code is immaterial now.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no solution that will have you only change 10% of your code here's how I'd do it:

First of all don't create new Instances of your main class (yes I understand german).
You always give it to other classes by using the so called constructor wich then stores it in a variable. So for example:

```
public class SpellInventory{  
    private Main plugin; //This is the main class you can access all public methods through it
    public SpellInventory(Main plugin){ //This is a constructor Method
        this.plugin = plugin; //The plugin class variable gets stored
    }
}
```

Now you'll have to instanciate the SpellInventory class and optionally save it in your Main class so you can use it from there.

```
private SpellInventory si;
@Override
public void onEnable(){
    this.si = new SpellInventory(this); //You hand over the existing main instance with "this" as argument
}
```

Now you're good to go and create something in the lines of a SpellManager class that contains HashMaps with the UUID of all players as key and some sort of boolean list as value that declares wich spells this player unlocked.
I won't spoonfeed it to you now I already helped you with the basic set up of a plugin you're good to go from there.